# await inside promise function

Tags: javascript, async-await, stream

How can I use await inside `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }` ?

Here's my code:

```
async function write_file(file1, file2){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = fs_extra.createWriteStream(file2);

    stream.write(await fs_extra.readFile(file1), async () => await fs_extra.unlink(file1));

    stream.on('finish', () => resolve());
    stream.on('error', error => reject(error));

    stream.end();
  }

}
```

I get syntax errors just like when I use await in non-async function, but even if I add `async before (resolve, reject) I still get syntax errors...

Comment: putting `async` in front of the `(resolve, reject)` allows you to use `await` inside the function, so your error must be coming from something else. What is the error message?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @Mason: There’s no `async` in front of the function that actually contains the `await`s (`(resolve, reject) => { … }`), and putting one there would be incorrect.

Comment: @Alex: Oh, that was your actual code? The `new Promise(` is missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t! And you don’t pass an async function as a callback to `write`, either. You’ve already read the file by that point, so you can delete it right away, or in parallel with the rest.

```
async function write_file(file1, file2) {
  const stream = fs_extra.createWriteStream(file2);

  stream.end(await fs_extra.readFile(file1));
  const unlinkP = fs_extra.unlink(file1);
  unlinkP.catch(() => {});
  // or just await fs_extra.unlink(file1);

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('finish', resolve);
    stream.on('error', reject);
  });

  await unlinkP;
}
```

Calling `stream.end()` after receiving its `finish` event doesn’t make much sense either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the functionality you want to achieve but if you want the correct syntax then it is as follows:

```
async function write_file(file1, file2) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const stream = fs_extra.createWriteStream(file2)

        stream.write(await fs_extra.readFile(file1), async () => await fs_extra.unlink(file1))

        stream.on("finish", () => resolve())
        stream.on("error", error => reject(error))

        stream.end()
    })
}
```

**Steps to correct syntax**

1. Put a closing bracket after the 2nd last closing curly brace.
2. Add **async** before (resolve, reject) on line 2.